# Protect a specific range on an excel sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a filter program that I want to apply. But I want to apply it on protected range : columns A:H.

I tried using this

```
Sub Protect()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "lemotdepasse"
'Placez ici vos instructions
    ActiveSheet.Protect "lemotdepasse", True, True, True
End Sub
```

*But it applies to the whole sheet. **I would like to apply it only on columns A:H.**

Comment: what is 'it', the protection or the filter? You protect a whole sheet.  You'll need to set the permissions on a specific range if you want the protection to apply or not apply.

Comment: Highlight the range you want to protected and right-flick. Under "Format Cells" you'll see the protection tab. Here you set these specifically to lock when you protect the sheet (if it's checked, you'll have to select all the other columns and 'unprotect' them.

Comment: Hello sous2817 ! "it" is for the ActiveSheet.protect code. I didn't manage to set the permissions on a specific range do you know how to do it?

Comment: Hello Mark S. Yes this is the classique way to protect the file but once I do this my macro that helps me filter the document doesn't work...

Comment: `myRange.Locked = False` where `myRange` is the range you want to remain unprotected

Comment: Actually my issue is that I have a filter program that filters the document from A to H but this range is also the range that I want to keep protected. So my idea was to unprotect the program at the begining and to reestablish protection at the end. However I didn't manage to reestablish the protection only on the range A:H

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Sub Protect()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Unprotect "lemotdepasse"
        .Range("A:H").AutoFilter
        .Protect "lemotdepasse", True, True, True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to use the filter when the sheet is protected?